# Setting value from a jquery var to a bean

Tags: javascript, jquery, javabeans

This is the jquery code

```
    $("#datepicker1").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(){

      var dateObject = $(this).datepicker('getDate');

    }});
```

And now I want the date from the  var dateObject to be set to a bean which is `setFromDate(Date date)` that takes a Date object as a parameter. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends how do u get data from request. Struts can do it using interceptor param.
if u do it manually in servlet than use SimpleDateForm to parse date

```
//should have same format used in datepicker
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat('mm/dd/yyy'); 

// i assume that request param name dateObject
Date date = format.parse(request.getParameter('dateObject') 
bean.setFromDate(date);
```

it is possible to assign date format in datepicker as well

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats